# How to get all records from table 1 and meta data from tabla 2 all together?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I want to know if theres any other way to get all record from table 1 (users) and all the meta data on table 2 (user_meta), I'm using right now this way:

```
SELECT 
u.id, 
u.username, 
u.email, 
r.role,
(SELECT val FROM user_meta WHERE id_parent = u.id AND attr = 'sidebar_color' LIMIT 1) AS sidebar_color,
(SELECT val FROM user_meta WHERE id_parent = u.id AND attr = 'profile_pic' LIMIT 1) AS profile_pic,
(SELECT val FROM user_meta WHERE id_parent = u.id AND attr = 'thumbnail' LIMIT 1) AS thumbnail,
(SELECT val FROM user_meta WHERE id_parent = u.id AND attr = 'bg_img' LIMIT 1) AS bg_img,
(SELECT val FROM user_meta WHERE id_parent = u.id AND attr = 'bio' LIMIT 1) AS bio,
(SELECT val FROM user_meta WHERE id_parent = u.id AND attr = 'google' LIMIT 1) AS google,
(SELECT val FROM user_meta WHERE id_parent = u.id AND attr = 'facebook' LIMIT 1) AS facebook,
(SELECT val FROM user_meta WHERE id_parent = u.id AND attr = 'twitter' LIMIT 1) AS twitter,
(SELECT val FROM user_meta WHERE id_parent = u.id AND attr = 'whatsapp' LIMIT 1) AS whatsapp
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN roles r ON u.id_role = r.id
ORDER BY u.id
ASC
```

And well it's working, i get all data from all users but I would like another way around, because I will be using the same approach for a CRM but this one is gonna have so many meta data and it's gonna be a huge query to maintain.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for reminding us of the joys of working with Entity Attribute Value (EAV) model.

Comment: LIMIT 1 without ORDER BY in the subqueries is unlogical because MySQL is free to return the record in anny order.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is fine and under many circumstances is the fastest.  But aggregation is also viable:

```
SELECT um.id_parent,
       MAX(CASE WHEN um.attr = 'sidebar_color' THEN val END) as sidebar_color,
       MAX(CASE WHEN um.attr = 'profile_pic' THEN val END) as profile_pic,
       . . .
FROM user_meta um
GROUP BY um.id_parent;
```

This would typically be a subquery in the `FROM` clause.

For getting information on *all* users, this can be faster than the `JOIN` method as the number of keys gets large.  However, if you are filtering down to one or a handful of users, you want to do the filtering *before* the aggregation for good performance.